# Why is my header background/color not displaying?

Tags: css

I have no clue what's causing this, the last thing I modified was my footer and I verified, it wasn't that. So as I have no clue what's causing this I don't know how to show you my code. I don't know if the error is in CSS or HTML, I might have to show you both but they both have 100+ lines. For now I'm gonna put the `footer` and `header` CSS code here.

```
 footer
{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px gray;
font-family:arial;
margin-right: -10px;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-bottom: -20px;
background-color: #a8a8a8;
                               }


header
{
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-right:-10px;
    margin-bottom:-20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
                                        }
```

Comment: They don't appear to have a set height or width, do they have content in them?

Comment: Your header has no height and no width. So the box is not visible and ofc the background isnt so too

Comment: @Fuzzyma I didn't need any before, and that would completely destroy my website's design idea.

Comment: Try to make up a demo at CodePen or similar that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Xero Inside the header there is my logo and a text thingy, you can check on my website.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your website. What's the issue?

Comment: is there any color showing? or just not the correct color? is there any content in the header/footer?

Comment: @azochz No, the background is just transparent. On my website there is what it is suppose to look like and [here](http://gyazo.com/962cab7aa5531c9b9c37222c6f9d9980) is what it's looking like now.

Comment: @ralph.m I tried on Codepen and for some reason it works there...
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sLkDH/

Comment: @ralph.m also, you can see the problem for yourself here: http://test.psichologique.com/

Comment: Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `test.psichologique.com` demo, your styles are failing because you have HTML comments in your style sheet. Change this syntax—

```
<!-- CSS CODE -->
```

to this

```
/* CSS CODE */
```

and your styles will work.